# NSData caching iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, caching, nsdata

I'm working on a snapchat-like app and I'm trying to cache the NSData representation of images and videos. I tried with NSCache, but that didn't work, every time the app went to background, all objects on the cache were removed, then I tried NSUserDefaults for caching, but that wasn't a good approach either. Although it works and data persists with NSUserDefaults, it takes up a lot of memory and I've read it's bad practice to store that kind of objects in this class. What are your suggestions for caching and persisting data besides the two mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Write your NSData into your application's Document Directory and read it when you need that data again in your application

**For Writing Data to Application's Document Directory**

```
//get the path of our apps Document Directory(NSDocumentDirectory)

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//the path is stored in the first element

NSString *path = [paths firstObject];

//append the name of our file to the path:  /path/to/myimage.png

path = path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"];

//store any errors

NSError *error;

// Write NSData to Disk


BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
if(success){
    NSLog(@"Success");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

**For Reading Data from application's Document Directory**

```
/get the path of our apps Document Directory(NSDocumentDirectory)

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//the path is stored in the first element

NSString *path = [paths firstObject];

//append the name of our file to the path:  /path/to/myimage.png

path = path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"];

//store any errors

NSError *error;

NSData *rawImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path 
options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

if(rawImage){
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:rawImage];
   NSLog(@"%@",image);
}else{
   NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```